# How to detect the time user started using their phone in the morning

Tags: android, google-fit

My app can be first opened any time durning the day.
But when it's opened I want to be able to tell when the user first started using their phone in the morning.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to listen while your application is running use BroadcastReceiver. As noted in the Android reference [site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) you cannot declare this in your manifest file. 
    public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
// THANKS JASON
public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        wasScreenOn = false;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }
}
}
```

If you want to listen all the time for the user actions, you need a service as below;

```
    public static class UpdateService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // REGISTER RECEIVER THAT HANDLES SCREEN ON AND SCREEN OFF LOGIC
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
        if (!screenOn) {
            // YOUR CODE
        } else {
            // YOUR CODE
        }
    }
 }
```

The codes are from [2](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/).

Comment: Thanks, I was aware that I can just have a service running and then save to the database. What I was thinking thought, was that there can be some Fit or Activities api that would tell me when did they wake up.